# Increase the buffer size of java.util.Scanner's nextline() method for Android

Tags: java, android, java.util.scanner

I have discovered that if the newline character `\n` is after 1400 letter characters in a stream, then `java.util.Scanner`'s `nextline()` method just returns the first 1400 characters. The second call of `nextline()` method returns the remaining characters before the newline character. It happens at least on the Android platform (API level 19).

```
String testString = "..........\n";  \\ assume that testSrting is of more than 1400 characters and the last character is newline '\n'
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(testString);
String output1 = scanner.nextline();  \\ returns only the first 1400 characters of testString
String output2 = scanner.nextline();  \\ returns the remaining characters before the newline character
```

Is there any way to increase the buffer size of `java.util.Scanner` so that `nextline()` method can return longer strings?

Comment: Switch out Scanner for BufferedReader? Or read the underlying InputStream directly?

Comment: That is one way. But I need the parsing features of Scanner such as nextInt(), etc. BufferedReader does not provide those things.

Comment: Its not clear what your problem is. Reading until a newline is what the nextline method is supposed to do. What do actually want?

Comment: @Deadron: As I mentioned in the post, for a very long line (more than 1400 characters), nextline() method does not return all the characters until a newline character.

Comment: @arnobpl  Have you written a test case that reproduces that this is actually the issue? You should write something unambiguous that can be verified by others.  Its possible that there is a bug but 99% of the time its your code or data causing an issue.

Comment: @Deadron I have not written any test case for that but I can confirm this fact by observing Logcat logs. From the logs, it is obvious that `nextline()` truncates a very long line (more than 1400 characters). I do not think it is a bug of the `Scanner` library, instead, it is a part of the design, i.e., having a limited buffer size for parsing.